# Color legend missing when export scene (.eps) from paraview

Tags: paraview

I want to export eps format image from paraview. The paraview version I am using is 5.4.0. When I export eps format image from paraview, the color legend is missing as shown as the figure. The text and the color legend is missing and only the tick label is there. I tried with and without rasterizing the image but still get the same output. Is there any setting need to be changed?

Thank you [image]

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in ParaView, it has been fixed for the upcoming release, 5.8.1

https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues/17639